# Can I use Comodo without filesystem filter driver

Tags: antivirus

I downloaded Comodo on 14.04 and it says filesystem not loaded so I went out and found some patches but I dont want to mess around with the kernel so can I use Comodo without the filesystem filter driver, will it work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use it without this options just you'll need to scan manually every time

But there is simple soution:

1) You can get this driver "redirfs,avflt,dazuko -- kernel 3.18 or lower" needed from here:

http://www.bondoffamily-net.com/~kinta-chan/techknow/DownLoad/DownLoad.html

2) Go to folder where you downloaded the driver:

`sudo mv driver.tar /opt/COMODO/driver.tar`

3) Then change directory

`cd /opt/COMODO`

4) Install it 
`sudo ./post_setup.sh`
(**Please be carefull** at end of licence you NEED to accept with `Y` and then you can add email address, and choose Language `8`)

5) Restart cmdavd
`/etc/init.d/cmdavd restart`

6) Reboot if must

7) RIGHT CLICK on System Tray icon and click

1. Antivirus Security Level
2. On Access

DONE!!!